# Input Validation For Function

Tags: c++, validation, loops, input

```
float getTestScore();
float score;
cout<<"Please enter a test score"<<endl;
cin>>score; 
return score;
```

I am making an algorithm that takes three test scores and calculates the average. I am using functions and this part of my function gets the test score. I need input validation because the score needs to be between 0 and 100, inclusive. I tried a do-while loop

```
do { /* ... */ } while ((score>=0) && (score<=100))
```

but that cause an infinite loop that repeatedly asks for a score. All I need are three score between 0 & 100.

Comment: Post the do-while loop you wrote.

Comment: it was do{ .....}while((score>=0)&&(score<=100)) @sputnick

Comment: @Ka112324 Do you have counter variable to check the number of inputs taken ?

Comment: the counter wasn't working, I initilzed it to 0 and put (count<3) as a  while-loop @Mahesh

Comment: It goes without saying that you incremented the counter, right? It's difficult to explain what you did wrong if you don't show the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

- Check first to see that your input is actually a number.
- If it is indeed a number, check to see whether it's in the range you need.